# Enable all HTTP methods on Apache

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, configuration

I have set up a completely plain Apache web server (version 2.4.7) on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS.

I want to enable other HTTP methods such as `PUT` and `DELETE` for some testing purposes. I edited my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and added the directive

```
<Location />
   <LimitExcept GET HEAD POST OPTIONS DELETE PUT>
       Allow from all
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

before restarting Apache.

However, if I use Telnet and type `OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0` I do only get `Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS` back, and not the methods I wanted such as `PUT`. What should I do to enable these methods?

Answer (score 2):

`PUT` and `DELETE` methods are enabled by default and are only usable with `handlers`.

**Example**

```
> a2enmod actions ; service apache2 reload

<Location />
 Script PUT /handler.php
 Script DELETE /handler.php
</Location>
```